# Page rendering differently in Safari - all other browsers OK

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to produce a HTML/CSS eBay store template for my friend.

It looks fine on my PC with Chrome and IE but on his Mac and iPhone (both using Safari) the layout isn't displayed as we would like.

On the left column, the menu items should be displayed at the top of the column but on Safari they are displayed at the bottom of the column.

Please does anyone know of a fix for this Safari positioning behaviour?

P.S. The out-dated table tags are automatically added when you upload the template.

[image: This is how it looks on Chrome]

[image: This is how it looks on Safari]

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="3" rowspan="1" height="15"><img width="1" height="15" src="http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/s.gif"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="top" id="LeftPanel" width="210" height="100%" style="word-wrap:break-word;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="v4thldr"><tbody><tr>

<td><div><div style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;width:100%;float:left;font-size:14pt;color:#FFFFFF">
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC;padding-left:5px"><h5 class="icon-title" style="font-size:16pt;padding:0;margin-bottom: 0.5em;text-transform:none">Title 1</h5></div>
<div style="clear:both;width:100%">
Menu 1 Items
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC;padding-left:5px"><h5 class="icon-title" style="font-size:16pt;padding:0;margin-bottom: 0.5em;text-transform:none;margin-top:20px">Title 2</h5></div>
Menu 2 Items
</div>
</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="v4thldr"><tbody><tr><td>

<div><div style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;width:100%;float:left;font-size:14pt;margin-top:20px">
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC;padding-left:5px"><h5 class="icon-title" style="font-size:16pt;padding:0;margin-bottom: 0.5em;text-transform:none">Newsletter Signup Title</h5></div>
<div style="clear:both;width:100%">
Newsletter Signup Box Content

<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC;padding-left:5px"><h5 class="icon-title" style="font-size:16pt;padding:0;margin-bottom: 0.5em;text-transform:none;margin-top:20px">Payment Methods Title</h5></div>

Payment Methods Content


</div>
</div></div>

</td></tr></tbody></table></td>

<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" width="13"><img width="13" height="1" src="http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/spacer.gif"></td><td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="top">
                                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                                                                    <table id="TopPromoArea" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"></table>
                                                                </td></tr><tr><td align="left" colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="top" id="CentralArea">
<div style="width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;float:left">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="v4stw">
// Long list of items here
</table> 
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
<br clear="none">
</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Your provided HTML works as expected in Safari 8... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOZvEE?editors=100 -- Please provide a fiddle, plunkr or codepen showing your issue. And for the love of everything, format your code before posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was due to reset.css declaring "vertical-align:bottom" which only seemed to affect Safari. I have now removed this line and is working fine now.